# Kubernetes - Where does it store secrets and how does it use those secrets on multiple nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Not really a programming question but quite curious to know how does Kubernetes or Minikube manage secrets & uses it on multiple nodes/pods?

Let's say if I create a secret to pull image with `kubectl` as below -

```
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=$USERNM --docker-password=$PASSWD --docker-email=vivekyad4v@gmail.com
```

What processes will occur in the backend and how will k8s or Minikube use those on multiple nodes/pods?

Comment: All secret-keys and configurations are stored onto [etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/). It is installed on all node of the cluster in order to allow K8s to access to these data.

Comment: `etcd` can be a completely different cluster or can just reside on the master. The nodes/workers just access the `etcd` data via APIs, right ?

Comment: You can install `etcd` wherever you want. When you will start the `kube-master` you have to specify the `ip:port` of the `etcd` endpoint. Big providers like Google or AWS install `etcd` as a K8s' pod often.

Answer (score 7):

All data in Kubernetes is managed by the `API Server` component that performs CRUD operations on the data store (current only option is `etcd`).

When you submit a `secret` with `kubectl` to the `API Server` it stores the resource and data in `etcd`. It is recommended to enable encryption for secrets in in the API Server (through setting the right flags) so that the data is encrypted at rest, otherwise anyone with access to `etcd` will be able to read your `secrets` in plain text.

When the `secret` is needed for either mounting in a `Pod` or in your example for pulling a Docker image from a private registry, it is requested from the `API Server` by the node-local `kubelet` and kept in `tmpfs` so it never touches any hard disk unencrypted.

Here another security recommendation comes into play, which is called Node Authorization (again set up by setting the right flags and distributing certificates to API Server and Kubelets). With Node Authorization enabled you can make sure that a `kubelet` can only request resources (incl. `secrets`) that are meant to be run on that specific node, so a hacked node just exposes the resources on that single node and not everything.

Comment: Hi @puja can you please provide me with a link/source to this information you have written here.

Comment: sure @muzijack I would recommend checking both the [upstream docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#security-properties) as well as the extended [design document](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/auth/secrets.md#flow-analysis-of-secret-data-with-respect-to-the-api-server). If you're interested in the security side of things, I would recommend checking the latest [CIS benchmark for K8s](https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/kubernetes/)

Answer (score 0):

`Secrets` are stored in the only datastore a kubernetes cluster has: `etcd`.

As all other resources, they're retrieved when needed by the `kubelet` executable (that runs in every node) by querying k8s' `API server`

Comment: Which means `kubectl` manages it out of the box by making GET & POST requests to the `etcd` datastore?

Comment: Kubectl can retrieve them. But when a Pod is scheduled on a node it's `kubelet` that fetches data from the API.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the only component that talks to `etcd` is the API server. Every other kubernetes component, such as `kubectl`, talks to the API server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wandering how to actually access the secrets (the stored files),

`kubectl -n kube-system exec -it <etcd-pod-name> ls -l /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd`

You will get a list of all keys (system default keys). you can simply view them using `cat` command (if they are encrypted you won't see much)